# Combine \footcite with \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I'm fairly new on using LaTex, so maybe this is a really simple question to answer. I've rewritten the whole question due to the comments made.

What I'm trying to do is to declare my own command that is just like `\footcite` but that exclude the year.

The problem is that I in some citation don't want the year to be printed, just the author. So in general the command `\footcite` works perfectly with verbose-ibid, but for some specific citations the year shouldn't be printed.

Here is an example of my LaTex code (which I hope is MWA):

```
    \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[swedish]{babel}
    \usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, labeldate, isbn=false, url=false, sorting=nyt, hyperref=true, pagetracker=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{200910rp162,
    Address = {Stockholm},
    Author = {Prop.{ }2009/10:162},
    Title = {Ers{"a}ttning vid expropritaion},
    Year = {2010},
    Keywords = {offentligttryck},
    }
    @book{Babcock1931rev,
    Address = {Ann Arbor},
    Author = {Babcock, Frederick M.},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan, School of Business Administration, Bureau of Business Research},
    Title = {Real estate valuation : a statement of the appraisal problem and a discussion of the principles involved in the development ...},
    Year = {1931}, 
    keywords={litteratur}, }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
\begin{document}

Some text that I have a citation on.\footcite[s. 12]{200910rp162}

And some other text I cite on another page.\footcite[s. 15]{200910rp162}

Text.\footcite[s. 12]{Babcock1931rev}

Text2.\footcite[s. 15]{200910rp162}


\end{document}
```

In my presented example footnote 1-3 is good. It's the 4th that is wrong, I don't want it to display the year (2010) for that specific source. But for "normal" literature I want it just like how `\footcite` works.

[image]

Edit:
Regarding the comment. I'm writing a book about Swedish Law, and it's customary to cite Government bills that precede a new law by the name of the bill, e.g. Prop 2009/10:162 and a page reference. That's why I put the name of the bill as author in my .bib. And I also put the { } so that it comes out as Prop. 2009/10:162, otherwise LaTex treats the 2009/10:162 as surname and put it first. For all my "normal" citations I perfectly happy :). It's just for this "Prop-citations" I'm struggling.

I tried to make my own command with:

```
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\footciteauthor}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeauthor}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

But it didn't work. I also tried the tips with `shorthand`. It works okay, but then the "ibid-tracker" doesn't work.

Final edit:
I manage to make my own solution, that I don't think is the best one, but at least it works for now. This is what I did (I reckon that it could be interesting if someone else has the same problem). First I took away all Year-entries in the .bib for the sources that I don't want year to be showed. Then I added this to my preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {\printtext{}}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printdateextra}}}%

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\printtext{}}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```

Sorry for long post :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would it be possible to prepare a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows what you are talking about. I don't think "Prop.{ }2009/10:162" is actually something one would want in the author field, so I assume one solution could be to use the `.bib` fields differently. You could try `shorthand` for example.

Comment: Thanks! I added som info about the question. Not sure what you mean by shorthand though.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Just use `shorthand = {Prop. 2009/10:162},` instead of `Author = {Prop.{ }2009/10:162},` in your example above.

Comment: I think I found what is the problem, it's my change to author-year for verbose-ibid. I now tried to exclude the Year in the .bib for the sources where I don't want any year. But then I get (n.d.) instead. I would like it to be nothing if Year is undefined in the .bib.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314914/35864 can help you then.