# Biblatex: Don't show n.d. when no year is given

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using biblatex/biber with several bibliographies for my book, and the misc-type, which is also a single bibliography (as a chapter), for legal documents. These documents often do not have a proper date or rather the date is part of the title. However, Latex gives me a "n.d." output, and I am wondering what I can do for it to not give a "n.d." when there is no year given?

[image]

To make clear, the reason for why I don't want to use the "year" field is that I deal with very different kinds of documents, which may either have no date or the date is in the title, because of which I prefer to simply "hard-copy" the whole thing in the "howpublished"-section and need to suppress the year, if none is provided.

MWE:

```
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

Test\autocite[2]{draftnotice}.

\printbibliography[title={EU Legal Documents}, type=misc1]

\end{document}
```

My lit.bib is as follows:

```
@misc1{draftnotice,
    Author = {{COMMUNICATION FROM THE COMMISSION}},
    Howpublished = {Draft Commission Notice of 2014 on the notion of State aid pursuant to Article 107 (1) TFEU}}
```

Check out my MWE on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/5445314wzbgkh

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Yes, but what is the @misc**1** entry type?

Comment: I have several bibliographies, among which several bibliographies with legal documents are. misc1 is European Union legal acts, misc2 is dutch legal acts and so forth. Otherwise it is not possible to filter them out. I will probably have to apply whatever solution i get to several of the misc-types.

Comment: I see. I didn't know one could add digits to standard types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of selectively removing `n.d.`:

`.bib` file:

```
@misc1{draftnotice,
    Author = {{COMMUNICATION FROM THE COMMISSION}},
    Howpublished = {Draft Commission Notice of 2014 on the notion of State aid pursuant to Article 107 (1) TFEU}}
@BOOK{Dodgson,
    AUTHOR =    {Lewis Carroll},
    TITLE =     {The Hunting of the Snark},
    PUBLISHER = {Macmillan}
```

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, german]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel} \usepackage[autocite=footnote, style=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\bibliography{mylit.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
nodate = {\ifboolexpr{test{\ifentrytype{misc1}} or test{\ifentrytype{misc5}}}{}{o\adddot D\adddot}},
}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm}
Test\autocite[2]{draftnotice}. A book without date\autocite{Dodgson}.
\printbibliography[title={EU Legal Documents}, type=misc1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In theory that would work, but it would also turn the date in my other bilbiographies off (aside from legal documents I also use ordinary bibliographies, e.g. with books and articles). Is there a way to specify this command for the misc1 type?

Comment: I don't understand: when there's no date, you don't want `n.d.` to be printed *only for some entry types*, and want it to be printed for all other types?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't show up for the misc-types.

Comment: I have a solution, but you have to repeat the test for each `miscxx` type.

Comment: Thanks! For a german entry, this does not work:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
nodate = {\ifentrytype{misc1}{}{o\adddot D\adddot}},
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
nodate = {\ifentrytype{misc5}{}{o\adddot D\adddot}},
}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a question: Is your document main language german?

Comment: yes. i changed the MWE for the international crowd to better be able to relate.

Comment: What you ask is already defined  for all types of entries if you load babel with the `german` option.

Comment: Im afraid I don't understand your answer. Originally, it gives me o.D. instead of n.d. (see my changed MWE), as that is the german translation. I.e. same problem. Changing the language option to german for your code example does not solve the problem for me, i.e.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
nodate = {\ifentrytype{misc1}{}{o\adddot D\adddot}},
}

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your code and thought you wanted to have `o. D.` in all cases. I'll try to see what can be done.

Comment: A good option would also be, if the date would simply not be shown for the misc-types, whether existing or not (it should however, if used, be possible to use for sorting.)

Comment: Your code was not correct: you can't re-define a string  several times. I've posted a code which works, simpler than yours. Please see if it's OK for you.

Comment: yes it works for me!